# Rotate node text and use relative positioning in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, rotating

In TikZ, I sometimes want to rotate the text within a node and then position the node relative to another. However, the approach below doesn't work as expected:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw] (first) {1};
  \node [draw, right=of first, opacity=0.5] {2};
  \node [draw, rotate=90, right=of first] {2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To solve this, I wrap the rotating node inside another node which contains its own `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw] (first) {1};
  \node [draw, right=of first, opacity=0.5] {2};
  \node [right=of first] {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [draw, rotate=90] {2};    
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is better, but not exactly as I want it due to the `inner sep` of the wrapper node. Explicitly setting `inner sep=0pt` causes the inner node to get the same setting, which is not intended.

I figure there must be some better way of doing this. Any ideas?

### Using anchors and rotation

Frédéric gave a nice solution to fix this problem by using anchors. However, I found it a bit hard to understand how it worked. With some experimentations I figured it out, and thought to include it here in case someone else have the same problem.

When using relative positioning (e.g. `\node [left= of ...] {};`), a point of rotation will implicitly be specified on the node. For instance, if we say `left=of ...` then the rotation will be around `node.east`, and with `above right=of ...` the point of rotation will be around `node.south west` (see below).

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw] (first) {1};
  \foreach \o [count=\oi from 0] in {0.1, 0.15, 0.3, 0.5, 1} {%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{90 * \oi/4}
    \node [draw, right=of first, opacity=\o, rotate=\angle] (second\oi) {2};
    \coordinate (second_rotated_center) at (second\oi.center);
  }
  \begin{scope}[red, very thin]
    \node at (second0.west) {
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.02, very thin]
        \draw (-1, -1) -- (1,  1);
        \draw (-1,  1) -- (1, -1);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    };
    \begin{scope}[dash pattern=on 0.1mm off 0.1mm]
      \draw (second0.west) -- (second0.center);
      \draw (second0.west) -- (second_rotated_center);
    \end{scope}
    \draw ([yshift=0.5mm] second0.west)
      -- ([yshift=0.5mm, xshift=0.5mm] second0.west)
      -- ([xshift=0.5mm] second0.west);
    \draw [>=stealth,
           decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with
             {\arrow[scale=0.5]{>}}}, 
           postaction={decorate}]
      (second0.center) to [bend right=45] (second_rotated_center);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is why we don't get the desired result with `[rotate=90, right=of first]`.

By specifying an `anchor`, we say which point to use on the node when doing the relative positioning. Hence, with `\node [right=of first, anchor=north]`, we say "place the node right of `first` such that the node's `north` anchor is at the appropriate distance away from `first`". Left alone, this will cause the entire node to end up below and slightly to the left of where we want it. However, if we now do `rotate=90`, it will rotate into the position where we want it since we are rotating around the node's `north` anchor. Note also that the anchor *must* be declared *after* the positioning.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw] (first) {1};
  \foreach \o [count=\oi from 0] in {0.1, 0.15, 0.3, 0.5, 1} {%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{90 * \oi/4}
    \node [draw, right=of first, opacity=\o, rotate=\angle, anchor=north] (second\oi) {2};
    \coordinate (second_rotated_center) at (second\oi.center);
  }
  \begin{scope}[red, very thin]
    \node at (second0.north) {
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.02, very thin]
        \draw (-1, -1) -- (1,  1);
        \draw (-1,  1) -- (1, -1);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    };
    \begin{scope}[dash pattern=on 0.1mm off 0.1mm]
      \draw (second0.north) -- (second0.center);
      \draw (second0.north) -- (second_rotated_center);
    \end{scope}
    \draw ([yshift=-0.5mm] second0.north)
      -- ([yshift=-0.5mm, xshift=0.5mm] second0.north)
      -- ([xshift=0.5mm] second0.north);
    \draw [>=stealth,
           decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with
             {\arrow[scale=0.5]{>}}}, 
           postaction={decorate}]
      (second0.center) to [bend right=45] (second_rotated_center);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: if you add `anchor=base` to the nodes in your first example, it rotates more or less at the current location. But the unrotated one shifts a little higher. So use it only when you want to rotate it,

Comment: That's really good doing the follow-up investigation, but I'd like to quibble with just one bit.  The `right=of ...` *doesn't* set a "point of rotation".  The node is rotated about its centre.  But it is then translated so that the specified anchor is at the specified coordinate, giving the impression that it has been rotated about that anchor.  What `right=of ...` does implicitly is to set this anchor and the `anchor=...` overrides this.  You can see this because if you put the `anchor=north` *first* then it is ignored.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Yeah, I suspected I wouldn't get it 100% correct when I wrote it, but better make a failed attempt than no attempt at all. ^^ Unfortunately, I don't really understand your explanation. More specifically, I don't get how the node being rotated around its center is connected with it being "then translated so that the specified anchor is at the specified coordinate". Could you please explain further? If you find it easier, you may edit my question to illustrate your point.

Comment: Nice follow up.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**method 1** You may achieve some of what you want by changing the anchor point of the node. In addition you may also change the `outer sep` or use `xshift`, `yshift`or `shift`. Be careful with the `shift`commands: the order in which they appear in the node settings has an effect on the result. For example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw] (first) {1};
  \node [draw, right=of first, opacity=0.5] {2};
  \node [draw=red, right=of first,rotate=90,anchor=north] {2};    
  \node [draw=blue, right=of first,rotate=90,anchor=north,outer sep=-4pt] {2};
  \node [draw=green, right=of first,xshift=-0.4cm,rotate=90,anchor=north] {2};    
  \node [draw=cyan, right=of first,rotate=90,anchor=north,xshift=-0.4cm] {2};    


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

**method 2** This is a modification of the answer from ignasi: rotate the text within the node and also specifying a minimum size for the node. Specifying a minimum size makes sure the node is square.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum size=1cm}]
  \node [draw] (first) {1};
  \node [draw, right=of first, opacity=0.5] {2};
  \node [draw, right=of first] {\rotatebox{90}{2}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: I like method one.  The point is that `right=of first` does two things: it computes the coordinate of the new node **and** sets the anchor of the new node accordingly.  The rotation doesn't change this anchor, so effectively rotates about the anchor.  Explicitly resetting the anchor afterwards corrects for this.  One could imagine a complicated setup which extended the `rotate` key by making it also rotate the anchor, but in the meantime explicitly saying `anchor=north` is probably the simplest.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to rotate it exactly around the position where it would have been placed non-rotated you could use this approach:

Place the node unrotated with `opacity=0.0` and store the coordinates at `tmp`
Place your rotated node at `tmp` and rotate it with `rotate around`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw] (first) {1};
  \node [right=of first, opacity=0.0] (tmp) {2};
  \node [draw, rotate around={90:(tmp.center)}] at (tmp) {2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As mentioned, the problem ist that the text has to be typed twice.
A solution would be to define a macro:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% Usage: \rotnode[options]{rotation}{text}
\newcommand\rotnode[3][]{%
  \node [#1, opacity=0.0] (tmp) {#3};
  \node [draw, rotate around={#2:(tmp.center)}] at (tmp) {#3};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw] (first) {1};
  \node [draw,right=of first, opacity=0.5] (tmp) {2};
  \rotnode[right=of first]{90}{2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Yes this is a good method.

Comment: Clever, but the problem with this is that you have to repeat the text content twice. So if you want to modify the text, you have to remember to do the change in both nodes.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I added a simple macro definition

Comment: Great way! Specially, this line" ` \node [draw, rotate around={#2:(tmp.center)}] at (tmp) {#3};`

Answer (score 15):

Another option would be to just rotate the text inside the node.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw] (first) {1};
  \node [draw, right=of first, opacity=0.5] {2};
  \node [draw, right=of first] {\rotatebox{90}{2}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is the only sensible method suggested here.

Answer (score 6):

First remark : The use of positioning is only useful here with the option `on grid` because after the rotation the distance between the two nodes are different from the initial distance. With `on grid` the distance is between the centers.
In the two methods, the use of  `coordinate` avoids the use `opacity=0`

Two methods, first one with the old manner `right of= first`. The code uses only one line
`\path  coordinate [right of =first] (tmp) ...`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw] (first) {1};  
  \node [draw,right of= first, opacity=0.5]  {2}; 
  \path  coordinate [right of =first] (tmp) node [draw, rotate around={90:(tmp.center)}] at (tmp) {2};
\end{tikzpicture}    

\end{document}
```

Second method with `positioning` and  `on grid`. Here the line begins with : `\path  coordinate [on grid,right= of first] (tmp) ...`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw] (first) {1};  
  \node [on grid,draw,right= of first, opacity=0.5]  {2}; 
  \path  coordinate [on grid,right= of first] (tmp) node [draw, rotate around={90:(tmp.center)}] at (tmp) {2};
\end{tikzpicture}     
\end{document}
```

In each case the result is the same :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A simple(ish) way is to use intermediate coordinate nodes:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Node 1
  \node [coordinate] (a) {};
  \node [draw] at (a) {1};
% Node 2
  \node [coordinate, right=of a] (a) {};
  \node [draw, opacity=0.5] at (a) {2};
  \node [draw, rotate=90] at (a) {2};
% Node 3
  \node [coordinate, right=of a] (a) {};
  \node [draw, opacity=0.5] at (a) {3};
  \node [draw, rotate=90] at (a) {3};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Note that the (a) coordinate name is re-usable, provided you "keep things in order".

I recognise that the internode spacing is different, so you may need to add a global node distance qualifier.