# TikZ-How can I address a point or specifiy a length in a rotated object?

Tags: tikz-pgf

First of, if anyone can think of a better title, please do not hesitate to edit it. :)

You see I have produced somewhat proper looking straight lines for the force vectors. I managed to do so after I calculated the additional (negative) lengths due to the tilt. Would there be a more elegant way to do this with TikZ's own tools?

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
booktabs,
tikz
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
%
\draw[thick, rotate=-20] (0,0) rectangle (0.2,8);
%
\draw[thick, fill=black, rotate=-20] (0,4) circle (2pt);
%
%y - tan(20°) = GK (OS)/AK (AS) -> (tan 20) * 2 = 0.72894...
\draw[thick, ->, rotate=-20] (0,4) -- (-2,3.27106) node[left] {\(F_{y}\)};
%z
\draw[thick, ->, rotate=-20] (0,4) -- (0.72894,2) node[below] {\(F_{z}\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

### Picture

[image]

Comment: Maybe this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45848/rotate-node-text-and-use-relative-positioning-in-tikz is related. Does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a `coordinate` node where you want it over the rectangle and use it later as reference point

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
booktabs,
tikz
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
%
\draw[thick, rotate=-20] (0,0) rectangle (0.2,8);
%
\draw[thick, fill=black, rotate=-20] (0,4) coordinate(aux) circle (2pt);
%
%y - tan(20°) = GK (OS)/AK (AS) -> (tan 20) * 2 = 0.72894...
\draw[thick, ->] (aux) -- ++(-3,0) node[left] {\(F_{y}\)};
%z
\draw[thick, ->] (aux) -- ++ (0,-3) node[below] {\(F_{z}\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]