# Rotate node and use relative positioning when using two lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, rotating

I'm trying to do something to do something very similar to this:

[Rotate node text and use relative positioning in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45848/rotate-node-text-and-use-relative-positioning-in-tikz)

Except I would like to rotate multiple nodes, and I end up with one node 'floating' above the other:

[image: example of wrong positioning]

Ideally I would like them to just be aligned next to each other.

Here is the example code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\scriptsize]

    \node(node1) [draw, rounded rectangle, align=center, rotate=90, fill=gray ]{Small text};
    \node(node2) [draw,  rounded rectangle, right = of node1, align=center, rotate=90, fill=red, anchor=north] {longer text \\ on two lines};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={font=\scriptsize}]

    \node(node1) [draw, rounded rectangle, align=center, rotate=90,fill=gray ]{Small text};
    \node(node2) [draw,  rounded rectangle, right = of node1.south, align=center, rotate=90, fill=red, anchor=north] {longer text \\ on two lines};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation: positioning uses appropriate anchors to measure distances. So if you say `right of`, it place the node some distance to the right of the `east` anchor. However, these rotations are not factored in, so after the rotation the `east` anchor is on the (now) upper end of the node, and that's why the red node got placed some distance right of the `east` anchor, i.e. the upper end, of the gray node. In this answer, Ti*k*Z gets told to use the south anchor instead, which is on the right end of the node after rotation. There is a slight asymmetry in the treatment because naively you might expect that Ti*k*Z would also use the `west` anchor of the red node, but it does not. I *guess* it uses `\pgfpointshapeborder` instead but I did not check this.

**EDIT**: The only edit I made was to replace `\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\scriptsize]` by `[every node/.append style={font=\scriptsize}]`. See [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52379/121799) for a discussion of `\tikzstyle` vs. `\tikzset`.

Comment: I've cleaned up comments here: comments can and often should be removed once they are not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

For the `nodes` to be aligned with the `baseline`, it is sufficient to rotate around the anchor to the `west`. So, remove the anchor to the north `% anchor=north` and move to the right of this anchor `right = of node1.west`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\scriptsize]
    \node(node1) [draw, rounded rectangle, align=center, rotate=90, fill=gray ]{Small text};
    \node(node2) [draw,  rounded rectangle, right = of node1.west, align=center, rotate=90, fill=red,% anchor=north
    ] {longer text \\ on two lines};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: right of]