# Oscilloscope rotation bug with Circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Does anyone know how to rotate the oscilloscope AND the signal square at the same time?

This is what I have so far:

[image]

As you can see, the signal does not rotate with the oscilloscope, this is what I wrote:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{circuitikzgit}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}[rotate=45, transform shape]
    \draw (0,0)node[oscopeshape](osc1){OC 1};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{center}    

\end{document}
```

I have tried using `\scope` and rotating from the node line, but the result is the same, I think this is a bug.

Also, I have used the last release of CircuiTikz, [this is were you can get it](https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45848/rotate-node-text-and-use-relative-positioning-in-tikz?rq=1

Comment: It's expected behavior - instruments behave like this, there is even an example on the manual, page 49. There is currently no option to avoid this , because I never saw circuits needing that...

Comment: @jsbibra - that do not apply. `circuitikz` is trying hard to un-rotate text and symbols in Instruments, as explained in detail in the manual, so those nodes  behave differently from plain TikZ

Comment: thanks for the update

Comment: @ElSabio --- I added a switch that will allow the behavior you want that will be in the next version; see https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/350

Comment: Thank you Rmano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple, in the case you are just trying to make a rotated element rotate as a whole, like my case hehe.

Just use the package `\rotating` and include your CircuiTikz there as a figure, that is all.

Comment: Hmm... But then you can't  nest it with other circuits. Nesting tikzpictures is not supported, and will give strange results...

Comment: This is true, but in this paricular case, I was trying to rotate a very big circuit to fix into a landscape A4 paper, so once I had everything on vertical, I rotated 90 degrees to fit it in the landscape format.

Answer (score 6):

It is well known that one has to use `transform canvas` with great care, and [John Kormylo reminds us about some of its side effects](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523055/194703). It is also absolutely unnecessary. Here is a trick that always works: use a `\savebox`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{circuitikzgit}
\newsavebox\oscopeshape
\sbox\oscopeshape{\tikz{\node[oscopeshape]{};}}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}[rotate=45, transform shape]
    \draw (0,0)node[label=above:OC 1](osc1){\usebox\oscopeshape};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. "always" refers to something that is not done by the viewer. `shadings` and `patterns` are examples of things that cannot be transformed with this trick.

Comment: P.P.S. To me it seems that the side effects of `transform canvas` are repairable. They seem to be due to a confusion between active and passive transformations.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt that this is bug, it is more missed (unusual) features demands (so far I didn't see electric/electronic schemes with rotated instruments). If you like to rotate ti, you should rotate canvas:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \begin{scope}[]
    \draw (0,0)node[oscopeshape,transform canvas={rotate=45}](osc1){OC 1};
    \end{scope}
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, this can introduce unexpected problems to overall scheme design ...

Comment: Yes, it does give an unexpected problem, it deletes the node.

Comment: Yes, see section 1.7. circuitikz has not been thought for arbitrary rotations --- so yes, everything can happen.

Comment: @Rmano, in a some of the next `circuitikz` release  seems to be very welcome to tie node contents of `oscopeshape` with its border.  With this (I assume) will works demands as was given in OP question or can be sloped as for example `\draw (0,0) -- node[oscopeshape,sloped]  {OC 1} (2,2)`. Frankly said, so far (in my long ee career)  I newer  need such way to draw oscilloscopes  in my measurement schemes :-)

Comment: @Zarko neither I ever saw those in 30+ years teaching electronics. It is not difficult to add; really similar to the `rotated numbers` in chips... Let's see. If the OP. can add a feature request with an use case in the Github page, all the better...

Answer (score 5):

Not an answer, just showing odd effects of the canvas transform.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \path (0,1);% for bounding box
    \begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate=45}]
      \draw (0,0) node[oscopeshape](osc1){OC 1};
      \draw (osc1.in 1) -- ++(0,-1);
      \draw (osc1.in 2) -- ++(0,-1);
      \draw (osc1.left) -- ++(-1,0);
      \draw (osc1.right) -- ++(1,0);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[red] (osc1.in 1) -- ++(0,-1);
    \draw[red] (osc1.in 2) -- ++(0,-1);
    \draw[red] (osc1.left) -- ++(-1,0);
    \draw[red] (osc1.right) -- ++(1,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

Alas, [remember picture] cannot handle rotation either.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[]{circuitikz}

\newsavebox\oscopeshape
\sbox\oscopeshape{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node[oscopeshape](osc1){OC 1};}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{circuitikz}[remember picture]
    \path (0,1);% for bounding box
    \draw (0,0)node[rotate=45]{\usebox\oscopeshape};
    \draw[red] (0,0) -- (osc1.center);
    \draw (osc1.in 1) -- ++(0,-1);
    \draw (osc1.in 2) -- ++(0,-1);
    \draw (osc1.left) -- ++(-1,0);
    \draw (osc1.right) -- ++(1,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```